# Understanding C# generic and upcasting

Tags: c#

Please see following examples:

```cs
class A : ISomething
class B : ISomething
class C : ISomething

private void AcceptsISomething<T>(T input) where T : ISomething
{
    if (input is A)
    if (input is B)
    if (input is C)
}

private void AcceptsISomething(ISomething input)
{
    if (input is A)
    if (input is B)
    if (input is C)
}
```

What's the difference of functionality between above two examples?

I think there is no difference because both function ensures that `input` has implemented `ISomething`, and in both function `input` can be successfully pattern-matched to the types which implements `ISomething`.

But I also think that if there were really no difference, then there would be no reason for the lauguage feature `where` to exist.

Comment: What if you need something that implements `ISomething` AND `ISomethingElse`? Or you want `where T : ISomething, new()` so that you can do something like `ISomething test = new T();` in the method? Can you do that with `AcceptsISomething`?

Comment: @John I got your point. You are saying that `where` can contain more constraints than mere upcasting, right?

Comment: Yep, indeed I am.

Comment: Also imagine if the methods returned their passed in argument to allow method chaining. The generic version gives you back an object of *the exact type* you passed in. The non-generic loses the type information and you have to cast back afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in your example there actually is no difference, but the WHERE constraint for generics is indeed very useful. By adding a WHERE constraint to a generic function, you can ensure that the used type is derived (or is) the the type in the constraint. By this, you also can use functions of this type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Your example is very simple, but in general there are a lot of things you can do with `where` only:

**Multiple constraints**

```
void AcceptsISomething<T>(T input) where T : ISomething, new()
```

**Inheritance**

```
class Base<T> where T : ISomething

class ChildA : Base<A>
```

**Return value**

```
private T Modify<T>(T input) where T : ISomething

var value = new A();
value = Modify(value); // vs (A)Modify(value)
```

**Concrete type**

```
private void AcceptsISomething<T>(T input) where T : ISomething
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}

A value = null;
AcceptsISomething(null); // prints "A" although argument is null
```